# Architecture Question: Services

Tags: c#, nhibernate, architecture, repository-pattern

VS2K8, C#. I currently have a solution with the following projects:

Core - POCO domain objects and data interfaces

Data - Repository pattern. Implements the interfaces defined in Core. Also has the mapping classes for Fluent NHibernate.

Infrastructure - Used for dependency injection, configuring nhibernate, etc.

Tests - Tests [tests for Core, Data, etc.]

Web - MVC2 web project

Now, with that being said, I'm trying to determine the best course of action for adding things like: Joining a mailing list, a contact information submission, etc.

I don't believe these should be in web. And I don't think they need to be placed in Data, save for when saving the mailing list information and contact information, fwiw.

It sounds like this should be placed on the Core level. With that said, if placed in Core it would rely on saving to the database. I'm a bit perplexed on where to place this and how to architect it. What route what you guys take?

Is this something as simple as just creating an interface on the Core level called MailingList with a method called JoinMailingList(emailAddress), and then implementing that interface on Data? This doesn't sound like the best route as it's a business concern. Thoughts?

Comment: Architecture question belongs to programmers.stackexchange.com http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/ .... Let the confusion begin!!!! We never needed the other site in first place.

Comment: Let's try to address it here. After all it IS A programming related question.

Comment: I think it's safe to place this on stackoverflow.com. It is a programming related question, and we are going to see code here. It certainly has some higher level architectural questions to it, but nothing outlandish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a services library and include service interfaces in your core library.

```
public interface IMailingListService
{
  void Subscribe(string email);
  void Unsubscribe(string email);
}

public interface IMailingListRepository
{
  MailingList LoadMailingList();
  void SaveMailingList(MailingList list);
}

public class MailingListService: IMailingListService
{
  private IMailingListRepository _repository;

  public MailingList(IMailingListRepository repository)
  {
    _repository = repository;
  }

  public void Subscribe(string email)
  {
    var list = _repository.LoadMailingList();
    list.Subscribe(email);
    _repository.SaveMailingList(list); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. You're going this route: 1. Create Services project/library with the mailing list service (IMailingListService) interface. 2. Create a mailing list repository interface in Core. 3. Implementing the mailing list service in Core. 4. Implementing the mailing list repository in Data (via NHibernate, for our example). Yes?

Comment: also note, that it should reference your core library but not your data library. You should have your DI container wired up at your website, which should reference both data and service libraries so the container can handle the dependencies for you.

Comment: close, the service implementation is in the services library. The interface (IMailingListService) goes in core, along with your repository contracts. I tend to create two folders in my Core library DataContracts and ServiceContracts for the respective interfaces to go.

Comment: That makes sense. I dig. I currently have a DataInterfaces directory inside my Core, so this works out nicely. Thank you, kind sir. Great stuff!